# $E=mc^2$ - why can we say that mass and energy are equivalent?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, mass-energy

Why is it that we can say mass and energy are "equivalent" if energy is equal to mass times the speed of light squared?

Comment: Why is it that we say prices in dollars are equivalent to prices in cents if the price in cents is equal to the price in dollars times 100 cents per dollar?

Comment: Good analogy given by @WillO but note that a priori there is no reason why we can define mass and energy to be the same thing, whereas in the analogy we have defined the price of an object then express it in two different units of currency.

Answer (score 4):

Because speed of light (in vacuum) is a fundamental constant. You can think of $c^2$ as a constant of proportionality between mass and energy. In fact, in theoretical physics we often set $c=1$ and $\hbar=1$, which is called natural units. Then $E=m$.

Comment: If two quantities differ by a constant factor, they convey the same information. Knowing one, you can always get the other by dividing or multiplying by the constant. It's just two ways of saying the same thing, like that price quoted in dollars or cents.